# Passing independent parameter to .mouseover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 32 html elements with the id names `nyg`, `nyj`, and some others. My goal is to bind a `mouseover` and `mouseout` event to each of the elements, so I can change the `color` of the box that the user is hovering over. This does not work, and I am sure there is a better way to do this while also being code efficient. I am doing this for 32 different teams, so efficiency is important. If somebody could lead me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <ul class="conference">
      <ul class="division">
        <li id="nyg" class="team"></li>
        <li id="nyj" class="team"></li>
        <li class="team"></li>
        ....
```

**JS**

```
var teams = [
{
    id: 'nyg',
    name: 'Giants',
    city: 'New York',
    color1: '#000099',
    color2: '#0000ff',
    depth: 'http://www.ourlads.com/nfldepthcharts/depthchart/NYG',
    offseason: 'http://espn.go.com/nfl/team/transactions/_/name/nyg',
    logo: 'logos/nyg.jpeg'
},
{
    id: 'nyj',
    name: 'Jets',
    city: 'New York',
    color1: '#006600',
    color2: '#009900',
    depth: 'http://www.ourlads.com/nfldepthcharts/depthchart/NYG',
    offseason: 'http://espn.go.com/nfl/team/transactions/_/name/nyg',
    logo: 'logos/nyg.jpeg'
}];

for (team in teams) {
  $('#'+teams[team].id;).mouseover( mouseIn(teams[team].color1)).mouseout( mouseOut(teams[team].color2));
}

function mouseIn(color) {
  $(this).css("background-color", color);
}

function mouseOut(color) {
  $(this).css("background-color", color);
}
```

Comment: in CSS ? : #my-id-one{background-color : #123456} ;  #my-id-one:hover{background-color : #654321} ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `ul` as a child of a `ul` - you need to place `li` between them.

To actually solve your problem you could amend your teams data to be an object, keyed by the `id` of the `li` elements, instead of an array of objects. That way you can directly access the required object on hover of the element. Try this:

```js
var teams = {
  nyg: {
    name: 'Giants',
    city: 'New York',
    color1: '#000099',
    color2: '#0000ff',
    depth: 'http://www.ourlads.com/nfldepthcharts/depthchart/NYG',
    offseason: 'http://espn.go.com/nfl/team/transactions/_/name/nyg',
    logo: 'logos/nyg.jpeg'
  },
  nyj: {
    name: 'Jets',
    city: 'New York',
    color1: '#006600',
    color2: '#009900',
    depth: 'http://www.ourlads.com/nfldepthcharts/depthchart/NYG',
    offseason: 'http://espn.go.com/nfl/team/transactions/_/name/nyg',
    logo: 'logos/nyg.jpeg'
  }
};

$('.team').hover(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', teams[this.id].color1);
}, function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', teams[this.id].color2);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <ul class="conference">
    <li>
      <ul class="division">
        <li id="nyg" class="team">NYG</li>
        <li id="nyj" class="team">NYJ</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```